# Why doesn't ReplaceAll work if following other operators?

Tags: replacement

I have a giant expression and would like to expand its factors and perform a replacement after it, like:

```
expression // Expand /. {m^k_ /; k > 3 -> 0}
```

but the result still contains powers of `m` much higher than 3. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Due to [the precedence of `/.` and `//`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/PrecedenceOfOperatorsInNotations.html), your expression is actually interpreted as `epxression // (Expand /. {…})` instead of `(expression // Expand) /. {…}`. You can use `expression // Expand // ReplaceAll@{…}` as a workaround.

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you very much!